# The Html ordered List is displaying in next line

Tags: html, css

I have used html and css code below My aim is to display master,image and list in single line.but list is displaying in next line so pls help me to rectify the issue.

HTML

```
 <h2> Master  <img src="<?php echo base_url('img/courses_title.jpg');  ?>" HEIGHT="55" WIDTH="55" BORDER="0"    /><div align="center"> <ul class="Data"><li> 1.Course code and name is created </li></ul></h2>
```

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">    
            .pg-normal {
                color: green;
                font-weight: normal;
                text-decoration: none;    
                cursor: pointer;
                 background: #e3e3e3;
                 border: 1px solid #cac9c9;
                 padding: 4px 7px;    
            }
            .pg-selected {
                color: black;
                font-weight: bold;        
                text-decoration: underline;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            .Data {
width:20%;
    margin: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius : 10px; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-border-radius : 10px; /* Safari & Chrome */
    -khtml-border-radius : 10px; /* Linux browsers */
    border-radius : 10px; /* CSS3 compatible browsers */
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #cccccc;
    padding: 0px;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #eeeeee; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%, #cccccc 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#eeeeee), color-stop(100%,#cccccc)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%,#cccccc 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%,#cccccc 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%,#cccccc 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #eeeeee 0%,#cccccc 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#eeeeee', endColorstr='#cccccc',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}



        </style>
```

Comment: Its not good to have `UL` and `LI` elements inside `H2`...

Comment: You need to add `float:left` to both `<img/>`s and `<ul>`.

Comment: There is so much wrong with your HTML. You are also not even closing the `<h2>` tag. The align attribute of `<div>` is deprecated in HTML 4.01.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GMFZ3/).

I have added an example based off your above HTML, here is the HTML code:

```
<h2>Master</h2>

<img src="/path/" alt="example" />

<ul>
    <li>1. Course code and name is created</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
img, ul {
    float: left;
}
ul {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's displaying in the next line because it is a block element.

> Most HTML elements are defined as block level elements or as inline
>   elements.
>
> Block level elements normally start (and end) with a new line when
>   displayed in a browser.
>   Inline elements are normally displayed without starting a new line.

That is the main concept, as to why your `li` appears on separate lines.

if you want your `li` element to appear on the same line, you'll have to implement it in the `inline` form, like so:

```
<li style="display:inline;">content</li>
```

if you want all your `li`s to be inline do this:

```
<style>
    li{
        display:inline;
    }
<style>
```

just add it to the `head` section of your page.

Answer (score 0):

try  this one

http://jsfiddle.net/nY6eu/1/

add this to your code

css file:

```
 .ul{
        list-style:none;
    }
    .ul li{
        display:inline-block;
    }
```

html file:

```
<ul class="ul"><li><h2> Master </h2></li>
    <li><img src="http://img.talkandroid.com/uploads/2013/03/wpid-photo-jan-14-2013-1115-am.jpg" HEIGHT="55" WIDTH="55" BORDER="0"    /></li>  <li class="Data"> 1.Course code and name is created </li>
    </ul>
```